# MBS Market Duration & Convexity

Tags: implied-volatility, duration, convexity, mbs

Soft question...hopefully.

I am working on a swaption hedging strategy. Part of this strategy calls for a forward looking indication of changes in implied volatility, using 1m10y implied as a proxy for movements across the rest of the surface. I came across the following paper which suits my scenario and approach well:

[Mortgage Hedging and Rate Volatility; Roberto Perli & Brian Sack](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8e81/7fc7037a2330469297631f00fa7f31cd7beb.pdf)

Perli and Sack use three variables to test whether the hedging activities of MBS holders has a material impact on swap rate volatility. In summary, they specify a Ordinary Least Squares regression with expected (implied) volatility of the 10Yr swap rate as the dependent against three explanatory variables:

1. The convexity of the MBS Market
2. The duration of the MBS Market
3. The amount of Mortgage refinancing

I have Terminal access so I can use the **MBA US Refinancing Index** for the Refinancing independent. Perli and Sack state that their data set includes weekly observations from "the effective convexity and duration of the Merril-Lynch master mortgage index" but I can't find references to this index anywhere.

I've tried various other searches for a composite MBS Market Duration/Convexity index, to no avail. *Any ideas as to where I could get data for the MBS Duration/Convexity inputs?*

Thanks!

Comment: Merrill Mortgage Master is M0A0 <<Index>> on bloomberg; you may need to get this index turned on for you to gain access via your terminal

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Merrill's indices have been sold to ICE; the rebranding might be the source of confusion.

Comment: @Helin...indeed it was.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be curious if you can get the convexity for the Merrill index.   Bloomberg/Barc MBS index only shows duration on the terminal.  That index would be my first choice. 
 Regardless, it might be most useful to calc the empirical convexity yourself to study a swaption hedging strategy.  Additionally, keep in mind the regime shifted dramatically since Fannie and Freddie (once the largest convexity hedgers in swaptions by far) became smaller.

Comment: M0A0 INDEX IND4 <GO>; you have to scroll down to see Effective Convexity.